# Stripe Apple Pay crash due to format does not match expected client secret

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

While using stripe apple pay when i make payment then app crash and showing error "Assertion failed: `secret` format does not match expected client secret formatting.: file Stripe/STPAPIClient.swift, line 593"

```
 let paymentRequest = StripeAPI.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: STPPaymentConfiguration.shared.appleMerchantIdentifier!, country: "US", currency: "USD")

    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "iTem 1", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: 10.0))),
    ]
    
    // Initialize an STPApplePayContext instance
    if let applePayContext = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: paymentRequest, delegate: self) {
        // Present Apple Pay payment sheet
        applePayContext.presentApplePay(on: self)
    }
    else{
        // There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration
        let alert = self.showAlert(withTitle: "Error", andMessage:"Unable to make Apple Pay transaction.", completion: self.alertAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: where do you get the error?  Do you process the payment through your server? Can you show us the server side relevant code?  Have you set up the `defaultPublishableKey` in the app? At what point of the payment transaction do you get the error?

Comment: Its crashing before calling server code, if stripe returns any success or failure then our server code runs but its occurs before.

Comment: have you  used 'STPSetupIntentConfirmParams'? I don't think the problem is in the code your are showing

Comment: I use In AppDelegate just 2 lines 

StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey = ""
STPPaymentConfiguration.shared.appleMerchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.appName"

Comment: in Controller 

let paymentRequest = StripeAPI.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: STPPaymentConfiguration.shared.appleMerchantIdentifier!, country: "US", currency: "USD")

            // Configure the line items on the payment request
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
            // The final line should represent your company;
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "item 1", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: 20.0)),
        ]

Comment: // Initialize an STPApplePayContext instance
        if let applePayContext = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: paymentRequest, delegate: self) {
            // Present Apple Pay payment sheet
            applePayContext.presentApplePay(on: self)
        }
        else{
            // There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration
            let alert = self.showAlert(withTitle: "Error", andMessage:"Unable to make Apple Pay transaction.", completion: self.alertAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }

Comment: and Two Delegate method 

func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {
        let clientSecret = ""
            
        completion(clientSecret, nil);
    }

Comment: func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCompleteWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
          switch status {
        case .success:
            // Payment succeeded, show a receipt view
            break
        case .error:
            // Payment failed, show the error
            break
        case .userCancellation:
            // User cancelled the payment
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

Comment: Please Check All Code of my side

Comment: next time please add that code to the question. It is quite difficult to find the problem reading code in the comment. At what point your app crashes?

Comment: Please check code in question i already mention this is the button tapped code and at this point present apple pay dialog and i tapped to pay with passcode button on dialog and crash my app

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a client secret — the code you shared has this:

```
let clientSecret = ""
```

So that's the problem and reason you get an error about it being the wrong format.

You need to create a PaymentIntent on your backend server and return the `client_secret` to your app and use it inside that STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock.

https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#create-automatic-payment-intent

For example you might want to look at the sample apps that use URLSession to communicte with a server to get that information from a backend server : https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/using-webhooks/client/ios/App%20(Swift)/CheckoutViewController.swift#L67-L98